# Why don't we care about the logical nature of a set in abstract set theory?

Tags: set-theory

I am reading *Fraenkel's Abstract Set Theory* and in the first chapter he says:

"The logical character of the objects called "sets" is of no importance to the mathematical theory of sets – in the same way as the results of arithmetical calculating are independent of what may be, in the view of the calculator, the logical or psychological meaning of number"

Honestly, I still don't get why we don't care about it. Thanks!

Comment: Somebody cares and the others don't. You happen to be reading a book written by some one who doesn't care.

Comment: It is consistent with the title of the book: *Abstract Set Theory*; it means that it is the *mathematical* theory of sets, whose valdiity is independent of the (at that time) very complicated discussion about the "philosophical" discussion about the nature of *sets*, like e.g. *extensions* of logical concepts (Frege) or "logical fictions" (Russell) or other.

Comment: Thanks @CaveJohnson! Can you anwser the question I made to Mauro??

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks again for clearing things up for me. I got tired of dogmatic introductions to set theory and I read on math-exchange that a more formal introduction with logical proofs and philosophical discourse would be this book. Do you think there is a better one? I've read already 4 introductions and I have some grounds in first-order logic and natural deduction.

Comment: The author didn't say "don't care", he said it doesn't matter. The point is that he's doing _axiomatic_ set theory - the theorems are exactly the statements that follow from the axioms; what a set _is_ doesn't matter, all that matters is we have "sets" with a $\in$ relation that satisfies the axioms. Exactly like when you study group theory - what the elements of a group really _are_ doesn't matter.